Flaws in modern file encryption
Assuming AES-XTS is used for encryption, the data has to be put into the algorithm first and probably processed in RAM. Which means that the unencrypted plaintext is somewhere in the dynamic memory. Is there a way to attack the RAM and retrieve the unencrypted data?

XTS is used for disk encryption, and this issue applies to more than just file encryption as secret keys/private keys are stored in memory as well, etc. If an attacker has access to that device, there's basically nothing you can do to protect against this. The main defence is to overwrite sensitive memory with zeros once you're done with it. You can also encrypt memory, lock memory, or do guarded heap allocations. Encrypting memory doesn't work well because key material has to be stored in memory, so the attacker can just retrieve that and decrypt the memory.

@samuel-lucas6 what if I cant overwrite the memory, because I still need my encrypted data for later to decrypt it? If you mean RAM, what if you freeze the RAM and read out the contents before it is deleted/during the computation of encryption? Could AES XTS be created as an ASIC in hardware so that it is not that trivial to restore the keys? I know there is power analysis side channel attack, but from my research it is not as effective when there is a hardware implementation than it is for software implementations

You wouldn't overwrite the ciphertext in memory because it's encrypted. You would zero the key, which would be derived (e.g., from a password) or stored somewhere encrypted to retrieve it for decryption. That's an attack that requires physical access, and zeroing the key helps. What are you actually trying to do? File encryption, disk encryption, or something else? Or is this talking about a tool like VeraCrypt or some hypothetical discussion?

@samuel-lucas6 Im trying to find modern attacks on large scale datacentres. so a lot of disk encryptions of many drives/servers. I am considering everything the market can do to decrypt the data or install some malware on the device. Imagine the attacker has physical access to the device and can force encryptions, there is also no password for encryption. Therefore using VeraCrypt (which also is shady cuz uses some russian algorithms that were proven to be weak) which calculates the key in RAM (RAM can be frozen/read out) doesnt come into discussion.

This is probably going to be too broad and very likely it isn't going to be about encryption per se. Note that the symmetric keys for disk encryption are often stored inside the drive or SSD itself, making it a harder to extract the key. That at least protects the data if the drive gets stolen. Disk cache is often encrypted as well, and RAM can be encrypted too. But in the end the root user can probably still access it This is why you'd expect modern systems to have a bit more roles besides root / user. Updating an app should require less access than reading all memory.

For e.g. RAM encryption take a look at this. Smart cards also may do something like this (by default). Note that this question is probably better suited for [security.se]. I can migrate it on request but pretty please first look for dupes. It would require you to enable your crypto ID on the security site.

If an attacker can read the contents of RAM - that is a very big if. Any modern OS doesn’t allow this easily; it would have been possible with MacOS 9 or Windows 3 twenty years ago, but not today. Today you would have to break into an application to a degree that it is “game over” anyway.
There are side channel attacks. Even though another process cannot read my data, it can be influenced by my data. That is difficult to achieve. Or you might steal my device and connect it to a machine that reads its memory. This is very expensive, very hard to do, and has the disadvantage that I know about it - for example, if my phone disappears I’d call my bank to lock my accounts so even with encryption keys you can’t get my money.
On macOS / iOS encryption keys are never stored in a way that an application can read it, Qualcomm has or is working on something similar. Apart from that, application developers should always erase memory containing sensitive data asap.

Yes, it's possible to attack the RAM and retrieve unencrypted data using techniques like a cold boot attack, where the RAM contents are accessed after a system reboot, or through direct memory access (DMA) attacks.

How exactly would you do that? For example, what kind of hardware could I plug into a new computer running windows / Linux / macOS for a DMA attack?
